# includes and the order at which they are called in C++, windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm a little confused at why this is and i'm sure it's a basic thing I should know if i'm programming in C++ but here is the question:

I have a "Windows.cpp" and at the top it has includes of

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Game.h"
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Screen.h"
...
```

In my Screen.h I have the following which obviously requires information from windows.h because of the use of *DWORD*:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

class ScreenServer;

class ScreenClient
{
public:
    ScreenClient( const ScreenServer &server );

    DWORD GetScreenHeight();
    DWORD GetScreenWidth();
...
```

The question is, why do I have to #include windows.h within Screen.h, when my "Windows.cpp" already has included it before "Screen.h" is included?

Comment: Another important note is that `windows.h` will sometimes have issues if it is not the very first header file in a given compilation unit. 99.99% of the time it doesn't matter, but every once in a while it will and it sucks to debug

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!!! I've got it as first so fingers crossed I won't have issues!

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

Because some other file that doesn't `#include <windows.h>` might include `Screen.h`.

A bit longer:

In general, you should always include the headers you need, where you need them, and not rely on them being included somewhere else. Use forward declarations where possible, but if you need a full type, include the header.

Comment: Ah, so it's because cpp files need to work independent of each other rather than in any order of loading?

Comment: @JamesT usually, cpp files are compiled independently, so yes (the exception is bulk builds).

Comment: A common rule I follow when writing a header file is that a cpp file that includes it as the first header file should be able to compile without errors or warnings.